# How can I limit the requested scope of my github oauth app so that users aren't prompted to authorize it for permissions it doesn't need?

Tags: github-api

According to the [api docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-the-authenticated-user), an oauth app can fetch some basic public info from users authenticated with it, without being granted a user scope.  I think this is all I really need for my app, so that a user can sign in with Github, but in testing, as a user I am always prompted to grant my app additional privileges.  I am not adding any scope query parameters or X-OAuth-Scopes headers to my authorization .  How would a github oauth app in this case be requesting scoped access for more information than it needs?

Comment: Just to make sure... Have you checked that you haven't previously given the application broader OAuth permissions?

Comment: @Potherca Yes.  It appears the scope is as I expected it to be without requesting any additional privileges.  I think the issue is that github is just different in how it handles oauth as compared to other social sites.  It's not quite as streamlined as google or facebook, and always prompts for authorization from the user.

Comment: ...which makes it appear as if the app is requesting protected information beyond public info, even if it's not.